# Site collection audit settings for Sp online using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, csom

I can set all the audit settings for my site collections using the following powershell script, works great

```
$Site= $ctx.Site;      
$audit = $site.Audit;      
$ctx.Load($site);      
$ctx.Load($audit);      
$Ctx.Site.Audit.AuditFlags = "All"
$Ctx.Site.Audit.Update()
$Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

The one thing I cannot do specify the location (document library) of where I can store audit reports longer than 90 days, there doesn't seem to be a way to specify that. Can anyone help with that part or point me in the right direction?

Documentation can be found here
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Configure-audit-settings-for-a-site-collection-a9920c97-38c0-44f2-8bcb-4cf1e2ae22d2?CTT=5&origin=HA102772739&CorrelationId=66158ec4-a3ff-4925-be13-1ab695ee38dc&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of the location is stored in a property bag.

You can set the value of the property bag easily using PnP PowerShell as:

```
Set-PnPPropertyBagValue -Key "_auditlogreportstoragelocation" 
-Value "https://site-coll-url/sites/test/Documents"
```

Or if you want to do it using CSOM in powershell, then it might be something like:

```
$Site= $ctx.Site;      
$audit = $site.Audit;      
$ctx.Load($site);
$ctx.Load($site.RootWeb);
$ctx.Load($site.RootWeb.AllProperties);
$ctx.Load($audit);      
$Ctx.ExecuteQuery();

$Ctx.Site.Audit.AuditFlags = "All";
$Ctx.Site.Audit.Update();
$site.RootWeb.AllProperties["_auditlogreportstoragelocation"] = "https://site-coll-url/sites/test/Documents";
$site.RootWeb.Update();

$ctx.Load($site);
$ctx.Load($site.RootWeb);
$ctx.Load($site.RootWeb.AllProperties);
$Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

Reference - [Set Audit Log Trimming using CSOM](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/902da4c0-5e1f-4687-8b43-7ec3449a2f6a/set-audit-log-trimming-using-csom?forum=sharepointdevelopment)

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked perfectly. Had a slight issue with access denied which was due to my account and access with the property bag but just put this at the top of the script 
Set-SPOsite "SITE URL" -DenyAddAndCustomizePages 0