# get audit log value CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, csom

I have problem how to create API get Audit log and get return value via CSOM?

when i try to this
[Site collection audit settings for Sp online using CSOM](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/248948/site-collection-audit-settings-for-sp-online-using-csom)

this is i can't get value it's only save to path.

how to get the value of audit log

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Online no longer uses Site Collection Auditing and no longer records entries.

You should be using the [Unified Audit Log](https://docs.microsoft.com/office/office-365-management-api/office-365-management-activity-api-reference), instead.

Comment: hi im using sharepoint server on premises. not using online.but it's same?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search the unified audit log via powershell, you will need to use the cmdlet [Search-UnifiedAuditLog](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/search-unifiedauditlog?view=exchange-ps) after connecting to exchange online.